# Problem with Brick texture and the Mortar Smooth

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes

I wish mortar smooth didn't fade between the tiles and the tile joints, as I'm using a bump map, which makes the tile smooth on the edges. I would like to have a clear cut between the tile and the Tile Joints, without blending, keeping the Bump effect of the "Mortar Smooth".

**Note:** I would like to make the tiles with the Mortar Smooth effect, i like the effect, like Subway Tile

How can I do?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple check if the factor/color is greater than *0* and transfer your predefined colors into a `Mix` node:

[image: Example 1]

Or if you want to create your tiles with the Mortar the other way around, use the following setup:

*Mortar Smooth* is always subtracted from your *Mortar Size* value proportionally, so you would have to use two Brick textures:

- one for your *Base Color*, where you reduce the *Mortar Size* by the value of *Mortar Smooth*
- and one for your *Normals*, which you can flip depending on the direction with the node `Map Range` for example

[image: Example 2]

And if you want to add the *Mortar Smooth* to both areas, you can mix these examples:

[image: Example 3]

Comment: This is really what I was looking for. It would be nice at this point to have the smooth on the mortar and on the tiles (Obviously this was not the question) but given the good result obtained, it occurred to me

Comment: @NoobCat If this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Image showing the node tree and a material preview]

Try adding a **Math node set to "Greater Than"** with the threshold set to 0. This will make any colour that is brighter than black white.

Then run that through a **Colour Ramp** to change the white colours back to red.

Comment: It could be a solution, but unfortunately, we cannot use the 2 colors of the brick texture

Comment: Another thing, I would like to make the tiles with the mortar Smooth.

Comment: a greater than after the fac output rather than color would let you use it as a mix factor afterwards while keeping the colors of the tiles